# How can i add data to <option> in Spring Boot from Relational Table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have s simple Java Spring Project with simple DataBase. My Tables "Park_lot" and "Cars" have relation @OneToOne.
How Can I add all information from one column "location" to , that used to add info to table Cars?

My models:
ParkLot.java

```
package com.valderosh.carrent.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class ParkLot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String location;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public ParkLot() {
    }

    public ParkLot(String phoneNumber, String location) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Cars.java

```
package com.valderosh.carrent.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Cars {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    //Fields
    private String brand;
    private String mark;
    private String segment;
    private String colour;
    private String power;
    private String drive_opt;
    private String status;
    private String fuel;
    private String transmission;
    private String image;
    private String number;

    //Relations
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cars", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Prices prices;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="park_id")
    private ParkLot location;

    //Constructor
    public Cars() {
    }

    public Cars(String brand, String mark, String segment, String colour, String power, String drive_opt, String status, String fuel, String transmission, String image, String number, Prices prices, ParkLot location) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.mark = mark;
        this.segment = segment;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.power = power;
        this.drive_opt = drive_opt;
        this.status = status;
        this.fuel = fuel;
        this.transmission = transmission;
        this.image = image;
        this.number = number;
        this.prices = prices;
        this.location = location;
    }

    //GetSetters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getSegment() {
        return segment;
    }

    public void setSegment(String segment) {
        this.segment = segment;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(String power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public String getDrive_opt() {
        return drive_opt;
    }

    public void setDrive_opt(String drive_opt) {
        this.drive_opt = drive_opt;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getFuel() {
        return fuel;
    }

    public void setFuel(String fuel) {
        this.fuel = fuel;
    }

    public String getTransmission() {
        return transmission;
    }

    public void setTransmission(String transmission) {
        this.transmission = transmission;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Prices getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void setPrices(Prices prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    public ParkLot getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(ParkLot location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

My Controllers:

CarsController

```
package com.valderosh.carrent.controllers;
import com.valderosh.carrent.models.*;
import com.valderosh.carrent.repository.CarsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class CarsController {

    @Autowired
    private CarsRepository carsRepository;
    


    @GetMapping("/cars-manage/add")
    public String carsAddpage(@RequestParam ParkLot location, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("parking", location);
        return "cars/carsAdd";
    }


    @PostMapping("/cars-manage/add")
    public String newCarAdd( @RequestParam String brand, @RequestParam  String mark, @RequestParam  String segment, @RequestParam String colour, @RequestParam String power, @RequestParam String drive_opt, @RequestParam String transmission, @RequestParam String fuel, @RequestParam String status,@RequestParam String image, @RequestParam String number, @RequestParam(required = false) Prices prices, @RequestParam ParkLot location, Model model) {
        Cars newCar = new Cars(brand, mark, segment, colour, power, drive_opt, status,  fuel, transmission, image, number, prices, location);
        carsRepository.save(newCar);
        return "redirect:/car-park";
    }

   }
```

HTML Template (with using ThymeLeaf)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>New Car</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header th:insert = "components/header :: header"></header>
    <h2>New Car</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col xs-6">
            <div class="container mt-5 mb-1">
                <form action="/cars-manage/add" method="post" class="form-outline col-md-8">
                    <div class="card mb-2 mt-2 border-secondary">
                        <div class="container my-2" >
                            <h5 class="card-text mb-2">Other///</h5>
                            <p class="text-muted mt-5">Segment</p>
                            <select name="segment" class="form-select">
                                <option value="Econom">Econom</option>
                                <option value="Standart">Standart</option>
                                <option value="Luxury">Luxury</option>
                            </select>
                            <p class="text-muted mt-5">Status</p>
                            <select name="status" class="form-select">
                                <option value="Free">Free</option>
                                <option value="Used">Used</option>
                                <option value="In Repair">In Repair</option>
                            </select>
                            <p class="text-muted mt-5">Number Plates</p>
                            <input name="number" placeholder="Number" class="form-control">
                            <p class="text-muted mt-3">LOCATION</p>
                            <!--Here i want to place all values from column "Location", table ParkLot to this option list named "location" -->
                            <select name="location" class="form-select">
                                <option th:each="park : ${parking}" th:value="${park.location}"  th:text="${park.location}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Create</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="col xs-6 mt-5" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Vo-uOewd9MJF9S5RMCcECaIV5r8d4iaIFZCIdWTfygwRFNB5Uf5NTOInEzzkNAK-Dd3bds5MMzFXgCONuv4tpBm86cnMGeGQ35Q5KgnquRGiaOikkXNV_7nlf2kRUfF9492r9gjVpyFntFiTCTnbXSe8gXmQE5TFY0ukvBesQ-ttPQprsg6oeCErPgjAsppky4Cw28xX7N1Tbk5yUMYEYFvGKjd8PioXyjJo1n5q5YURRLfM_kD7T4JOfEbABxFxfSP0o5vqpln8KY2piwn7JKy7yoqocVCv9EACixyH-utDYe0BFRgcEqRmmujtmPbrnBTMwXX9V0D1dw7gbXlJoS9GBTX_MIprkuZ8RAkGxdc1rLMuMQZwJ3GR415uPCOSKRtkv9qS5pe41ADi5MaWFM7CRNtkevdq9IXQ7iachfISV5dt0fvov_uw1TFHIfGkn7v7wRHFsXOx_dIh4n04mxut2MfZXHNV7LPJOSScAKsZpwRUeCXWK6zXmBoa1kxZmsOw3P2NVwHriBnxjicfgIe5Yo7AbXMKX1ly0X1K3vlKV4CN2YOQ8sq2RhPnxEknXO3HNbz8nw2nj1KRliYcCiHSfPVYReI_7N3hz4gKCr8S-8ZsqZrIyizpXvpXmu3mzMtASLw-BeYHfcXqr4qF6AFREIgMJQMdVY-ZyWL8Wqpqr2x1lpQ3kl1Z56tbXHGVh5tbHBc370yTIf0LdDa65OfQdTH9ItDgTf4yh7ZAX_xRcv8eg5SYYKLkqodrvUIlxanVXDzY4aIh3YAvUP4M0JwgNilxiwBGmSLJGM_3P2E3RN08YrSb4brpb_PXt7rnkUFMoru6ig4kMjKCZsjw5Dv49LUiqxjrZLDEGIIuspiDuh_LmhsXV2FnmBygcP9GsMgxlJf7UA=s800-no?authuser=4" height="600" width="400">
    </div>

    <footer th:insert = "components/footer :: footer"></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i started app and foint to "carAdd" Page i have this exception:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-05-29 01:49:33.565  INFO 16404 --- [           main] c.valderosh.carrent.CarrentApplication   : Starting CarrentApplication using Java 15.0.2 on LynxPad with PID 16404 (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Java\Spring\Projects\carrent\target\classes started by Lynx in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Java\Spring\Projects\carrent)
2022-05-29 01:49:33.567  INFO 16404 --- [           main] c.valderosh.carrent.CarrentApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-05-29 01:49:34.810  INFO 16404 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-05-29 01:49:34.944  INFO 16404 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 120 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-05-29 01:49:35.886  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-29 01:49:35.902  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-29 01:49:35.902  INFO 16404 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-05-29 01:49:36.055  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-29 01:49:36.055  INFO 16404 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2387 ms
2022-05-29 01:49:36.364  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-05-29 01:49:36.440  INFO 16404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-05-29 01:49:36.488  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-05-29 01:49:36.606  INFO 16404 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-05-29 01:49:36.779  INFO 16404 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-05-29 01:49:36.808  INFO 16404 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2022-05-29 01:49:37.696  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-05-29 01:49:37.705  INFO 16404 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-05-29 01:49:37.772  WARN 16404 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-05-29 01:49:38.740  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@63d66761, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@e645600, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@37753b69, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@39004e4f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4ec37a42, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@78d61f17, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@47d4e28a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@434a8938, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@74c04377, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1ab1d93d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6e78177b]
2022-05-29 01:49:39.463  INFO 16404 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-29 01:49:39.483  INFO 16404 --- [           main] c.valderosh.carrent.CarrentApplication   : Started CarrentApplication in 6.485 seconds (JVM running for 7.21)
2022-05-29 01:50:10.206  INFO 16404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-29 01:50:10.206  INFO 16404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-29 01:50:10.209  INFO 16404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2022-05-29 01:50:14.304  WARN 16404 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'location' for method parameter type ParkLot is not present]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your GET request you should specify the location parameter which will match your method parameter `@RequestParam String location`:

Example:
`"/cars-manage/add?location=<your location>"` and in your method signature should be String like :

```
@GetMapping("/cars-manage/add")
public String carsAddpage(@RequestParam String location, Model model)
```

It's also possible binding parameters as Map and Lists.

Example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param